# Persian character rendering in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, utf-8, persian

I have some NodeJs app with EJS‌ front rendering.

**app.js** contains :

```
var info={sess:req.session.user,data:rows[0],adata:allans};
res.render('datatable.ejs',info);
```

**rows[0]** is from mysql database that fully configured with utf-8 (shows true characters in python)

and **datatable.ejs** is :

```
......
<tbody>
    <% for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {%>
        <tr class="<%= (i%2==0? "success":"info") %>">
            <td><%= data[i].CompanyName %></td>
            <td><%= data[i].Owner %></td>
            <td><%= data[i].Country %></td>
            <td><%= data[i].State %></td>
            <td><%= data[i].SSN %></td>
            <td><%= data[i].Address %></td>
            <td><%= data[i].PostalCode %></td>
            <td><%= data[i].MobileNumber %></td>
            <td><%= data[i].PhoneNumber %></td>
            <td><%= data[i].Head %></td>
            <td><%= data[i].EconomicCode %></td>
            <td><%= data[i].WarehouseCode %></td>
            <td><%= data[i].MilkingCows %></td>
            <td><%= data[i].InHouseVet %></td>
            <td><%= data[i].Specialist %></td>
        </tr>
    <% } %> 
</tbody>
......
```

it works truly showing English strings. But for Persian strings it shows **"Ø¬ÛŒ"** instead of the true characters.

How to solve this problem?

thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried setting unicode charset in a page `<meta charset="utf-8">` ? And check that `datatable.ejs` file itself is also UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: tried this already! both setting U said is true. but not work.